# How to set a dashboards on Grafana home page?

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I have several dashboards in the Grafana, when I log in to the Grafana, I encounter with the `Dashboard Not Found` error.

I want to set one of the Grafana dashboards as the home page (default page) when I log in to the Grafana.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### Grafana v4.6.3

In grafana click on the Grafana Menu, got to  > Profile and under preferences you can set the Home Dashboard for yourself. For you organization you'll need to logon as an admin and under Grafana Menu >  Main Org > Preferences you can set the home dashboard for your organization. This is for v4.6.3, but it should be the same in previous version.

**Update for July 2020**

Seeing as this answer is still getting up votes I've decided to update it to cover later versions of Grafana

### Grafana versions 5.4.5, 6.7.3, 7.1.0

The same method works for all of these versions.

As ROOT says below: To set a dashboard as a default, or include it in the list of dashboards that can be used as the default, you need to favourite that dashboard as follows:

1. Open the dashboard you want as the default
2. Mark it as favourite dashboard

   - To do this click on the star icon in the dashboard header (in version 7+ the start is on the right-hand side)

#### Setting the default dashboard for yourself

To set a default dashboard for yourself do the following:

1. Select Preferences from the Profile menu (you'll find this toward the bottom of the Grafana menu bar on the left side of the screen)
2. In the Preferences view, under the Preferences group select the Home Dashboard you want as your default
3. Click on Save

#### Setting the default dashboard for a team

To set a default dashboard for a team you need admin rights. To set the default dashboard for a team:

1. Select Teams from the Configuration menu on Grafana menu bar
2. In the Teams view, select the team you want by clicking on it
3. In the Team view, select the Settings tab
4. Under the Preferences group select the Home Dashboard you want as your default
5. Click on Save

#### For an organization

To set the default dashboard for an organization you need admin rights, and you need to be in the Organization profile. You can set which organization profile you're in on the Profile menu.

To set the default dashboard for the organization do the following:

1. Select Preferences from the Configuration menu on the Grafana menu bar
2. In Preferences view, under the Preferences group select the Home Dashboard you want as your default
3. Click on Save

Comment: For Grafana v5 you should star the dashboard first, then it will appear in the dropdown select box for home page.

Comment: Is there a way to programatically do this?

Comment: In grafana 8.5.2 I have starred preferred dashboard, but after page reloading grafana shows list of dashboards (one of the now starred). How to make grafana open starred dashboard every time I open grafana ip:port ?

Comment: @leeman24 and others: you can do it programatically by using the [HTTP Preferences API](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/preferences/) (either for a user or for an organization)

Answer (score 2):

The recent grafana version(v9) of configuration is to:

1. go to `Preferences` in the menubar.
2. select your dashboard in the `Home Dashboard` dropdown.

this will updates the home dashboard to the whole organization.

Answer (score 1):

You can set via preferences, first login with admin user and then set home dashboard to whatever you want. Make sure you have starred it first before setting default one.

Answer (score 1):

you should star a dashboard first ,then at  preferences you can choose one you like!